# Stratified random sample when setting training and testing dataset

Tags: r, training-data, sampling

I am trying to divide my dataset into a training dataset  to fit a linear model and a testing dataset to carry out prediction using the model. Proportion or 80%-20%.

My issue is that my original dataset has a variable with a 90%-10% split between its two possible factors.
I am trying to keep that proportion constant across both the training and testing dataset so the model created and the prediction are carried out on datasets similar to the original dataset as the 80%-20% split risks the posibility of having too much or too little of one factor in the testing dataset.

I am not giving too much detail as this is part of my dissertation project.

I simply want to get an idea on how to keep the proportion working.

Thank you.

Comment: I suppose you could just split the data along your 90:10 variable, split each of those independently in 80:20 training/testing split and recombine. Then you'd always have your variable at 90:10 in both sets. This isn't really a programming question though.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a specific programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow. If you have general questions about the appropriate use of statistical sampling methods, then you should ask such questions over at [stats.se] instead. You are more likely to get better answers there.

Comment: This question was more focused if there was any specific fucntion in R to do this but I guess you are right and it isnt specifically a programming question. Thanks for both your answers